# HTML image not showing why

Tags: html, image, src

code:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.in/" target=_main> <img src="th.jfif" alt="website" width="100"></a>
```

Why am I not able to see any image here to open amazon?
NOTE: image is saved as th.jfif on my desktop and not in any folder

was expecting to see the image

Comment: Is your webpage also on your desktop?

Comment: I'd bet the path to the image isn't correct. You should familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is very likely due to your image not being in the correct location from where your `img` is expecting it to be.

I would say take the image from your desktop and place it in a folder, maybe called `site`. Then put your HTML file and image file in the same `site` folder and load your page again. Then your path mapping should be accurate and your image will render.

I say it is your path mapping because rendering your HTML link using an online image works just fine.

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.in/" target="_blank"> <img src="https://turnerduckworth.com/sites/default/files/styles/case_study_single_image_s_2x/public/2019-03/5_Amazon_Lettermark_2560.jpg?h=a92f03cd&itok=2nBmNv14" alt="website" width="100"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is to do with having no file or folder structure. Your image and web page must be detailed relatively to each other.

```
<img src="  path to the image from the web page location   ">
```

If your web page has a folder with it called `images` and inside it are all your.... images.

The path will be

```
src="images/picture-title.jpg"
```

Read about file structure. To  begin with, put your web page inside a folder of it's own and also in that folder create an `images` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the path does not match the location of the image you saved. the whole tutorial is on [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) .

for the example, you saved your image in path `images` , so you should should type it like this:

```
<img src="/images/th.jfif.jpeg">
```

and don't forget to write down the image file extension clearly. hope its help